# How to add Python package to Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am new to Azure, how do I get to install a Python package for an App Function? I followed the steps to add the required package into the `requirement.txt` file in the `wwwroot` folder. However this does not work. I also tried installing the package directly in the code (`init.py` )but that doesn't work wither.

Also, I cannot access the Kudu console.

How do install the required python packages I need for my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Now Ideally, we add the `requirements.txt` with the source code files and deploy them together as project and during the deployment process all the dependencies will be installed.
- Here the file structure should look like this :-
  [image]

where the `requirments.txt` is in the root directory of your project. Also, here I am installing `flask and django` along with this function. Now after we deploy this function, the packages will appear in the app service.

- Now my http trigger function is like this where it basically returns the version of the `flask` package

```
import azure.functions as  func 
from  importlib.metadata  import  version
def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse: 
    return  func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {version('flask')}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
```

[image]

Here I have deployed the function using the VScode extensions.

The other option would be to use the Console from the portal